# Port forwarding does not work when connected to wifi

Tags: port-forwarding

I am having trouble with port forwarding.

I have a server running on localhost:12345 and I have enabled portforwarding on my modem to access the service using my staticIP:12345.

If I am using 4G network on my phone I can access the service on staticIP:12345 without any problem but if I connect to my wifi I cannot access the service using staticIP:12345 but if I try the localhost:12345 everything works.

My network setup is a modem provided by the Internet provider and 2 mesh router airtier 4920 again provided by the provider.

Shouldnt i be able to acces the service using the staticIP even if I am connected to my own WiFi

Answer (score 1):

Port forwarding rules typically do not apply to connections originating from *within* your network.

When you attempt to connect to your server while on this particular WiFi network via your static *public* IP address, you are still connecting from within your network and the port forwarding rule cannot be applied.

This rule only defines how incoming connections from your WAN (not your LAN) will be directed to the specified port on your network. The fact that it fails when you attempt connect from an internal address is perfectly normal.

All you need to do is ensure that you connect using your server's *private* IP address while connected to this WiFi network and only use the public IP address when you are not connected to the same network (either wired or wirelessly.)

Comment: "Port forwarding rules do not apply to connections originating from within your network." Wrong, if the router supports [Nat Loopback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation#NAT_loopback).

Comment: I've added "*typically*" as a qualifier but clearly the OP's router doesn't have NAT loopback support (or it's not enabled) or he wouldn't be asking this question in the first place!

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Now I just need to see if my network setup supports that option